# How do I change the ROM in the FUSE emulator?

Tags: emulator, rom

I installed FUSE, and I can get it to run ZX Spectrum 48 games, but I can't figure out how to switch to the 128 ROM, even though I have the ROM. How do I change the ROM?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that running `fuse --tape <rom>` will load the ROM. Running `fuse --tape /usr/share/fuse/tape_128.szx` on Ubuntu loads the 128 ROM.